javascript read google sheet value.getBatch issue
I could use javascript fetch() to read a google sheet single value without an issue. However, when tried reading multiple ranges, get error 403.
This code works fine:
const apiKey = 'key-here'; 
const spreadsheetId = 'sheet-id-here';
const sheetName = 'Sheet1';

values = values = fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${sheetName}?key=${apiKey}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then (data => console.dir (data))
.catch(error => console.error('Google Sheet Reading Error: ', error));

but when replace the fetch() with values.getBatch, Browser's Inspect panel displays error 403:
values = fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet?ranges=Sheet1!A1:A2&ranges=subtitle!B1:B2?key=${apiKey}`)

The error is:
code: 403
message: "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API."
status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"

The doc about values:getBatch is at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading

Please provide your whole code, for the community to have better oversight on your project. It seems that it might be an authentication focused question but there is a lack of information on your code posted. Thank you.

Just added  the 2 variables declared above the code I described. You're probably right about Authentication issue. But the code was able to read single value from the sheet fine!

Modification points:

In your script, I think that ? of ?key=${apiKey} should be &. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of PERMISSION_DENIE.

Also, please do the URL encode as follows.

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet?ranges=ranges=Sheet1!A1%3AA2&ranges=subtitle!B1%3AB2&key=${apiKey}



When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
values = fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet?ranges=Sheet1!A1%3AA2&ranges=subtitle!B1%3AB2&key=${apiKey}`)


Tanaike, the genius is here! I thought I tried all possible combinations already. But your suggestion made it worked!! THANKS

@Kim Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
